# DoEvents: Dispatcher.Invoke vs. PushFrame

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

Recently I found a method that performs all pending messages in the dispatcher queue until a specified priority. I already had such code before, but they use completely different methods. Here's both of them:

The PushFrame way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enters the message loop to process all pending messages down to the specified
/// priority. This method returns after all messages have been processed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="priority">Minimum priority of the messages to process.</param>
public static void DoEvents(
    DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        priority,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

private static object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame) f).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
```

Source: [MSDN Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe)

The blocking Invoke way:

```
private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate { };

/// <summary>
/// Processes all pending messages down to the specified priority.
/// This method returns after all messages have been processed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="priority">Minimum priority of the messages to process.</param>
public static void DoEvents2(
    DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(EmptyDelegate, priority);
}
```

Source: [Blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx)

Which is better and are there any functional differences between the two solutions?

**Update:** Here's number two with the delegate inlined, as in number one, making it even shorter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes all pending messages down to the specified priority.
/// This method returns after all messages have been processed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="priority">Minimum priority of the messages to process.</param>
public static void DoEvents2(
    DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate { }), priority);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question. It doesn't matter much which you pick since both do the same in the background.

Both run into this:

```
While (dispatcherFrame.Continue)
{
  Dispatcher.GetMessage();
  Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatch();
}
```

However PushFrame is a bit nicer since you do not need to create empty delegate.

Comment: Well, I need to create a delegate either way, and the PushFrame code is longer altogether. I just pulled out the static delegate instance (which my source already did) because I believe it might be a little faster to keep the memory allocated. But it's probably insignificant and I could as well inline that part, resulting in a single method. But it's good to know that both are actually the same.

Comment: When using PushFrame, there is a problem with the main window re-size and move. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807292/wpf-application-intermittently-hangs-when-using-dispatcher-invoke-and-or-dispatcher-pushframe-while-user-is-resizing-or-draging-window